# Passing array into constructor parameter and creating an array of structs using the value of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers

I am currently writing a class for a polygon that will be drawn onto the screen. My problem however, is that I am unable to figure out how to create an array of structs from an array of arrays (which hold integers, for x and y of each vertex). I am passing this array through the constructor. I assume my error is to do with trying to pass a pointer as an integer, although, after perilous research I can not seem to get my head around how to solve my error. I come from a background of dynamically typed languages (Js and Python mainly) and this is my first large project in a statically typed language. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
struct Point {
    int x , y;
};
```

```
class Polygon
{
private:
    Point centre;

    Polygon(int x, int y, int vertices[]) {
        centre = {x, y};
        struct Point points[sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(vertices[0])] = {vertices};
    }

    //etc....
};
```

```
//Example of how it will be called in main.cpp
int main{
    Polygon polygon(0, 0, {{5,5}, {-5,5}, {5,-5}, {-5,-5}} );
}
```

Comment: Based on how you want to call that it looks like you want a `std::initializer_list<Point>` as third argument

Comment: There's however a lot of other issues in the code as well, such as the fact that the constructor is private and that nothing about the line `struct Point vertices[sizeof(vertices)] = {vertices};` makes sense in C++ (and won't compile because you are using the same variable name for two different things)

Comment: `sizeof(vertices)` does not give you the number of elements. Secondly, VLAs are not standard C++. Third, use a vector.

Comment: If VLAs are not standard in c++ what would you suggest for me to solve my problem? @ChrisMM

Comment: That'd be the "use a vector" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
struct Point {
    int x , y;
};

class Polygon
{
private:
    Point m_centre;
    std::vector <Point> m_vec_vertices;
public:

    Polygon(const Point& centre, const std::vector<Point> &vertices)
    :m_centre(centre), m_vec_vertices(vertices) { }

    //etc....
};

int main(){
    Polygon polygon({0, 0}, {{5,5}, {-5,5}, {5,-5}, {-5,-5}} );
}
```

You defined a point class, in the `Polygon` constructor why not use it instead of `x` and `y` right?